# fscanf doesn't read into an array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I've been trying to fill a struct array with strings from a file, but fscanf won't do. The code compiles just fine, but when I test it (if the array is actually filled), nothing comes out, as if nothing was done.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct p{
        char name[21];
        char lname[21];
    } Person;

    int main() {

    FILE *in;
    Person array[100];
    int i, n;

    in=fopen("people.txt", "r");

    if (in == NULL ) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    n=0;

    while( fscanf(in, "%s %s", array[n].name, array[n].lname) != EOF) 
        n++;
*// Here I've tried even with >0 or  == 2, nothing worked) //* 


    fclose(in);


    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s %s\n", array[i].name, array[i].lname);

    return 0;
    }
```

This is the .txt file:

```
Steven Stevenson 
Mark Ronson 
Jeff Jefferson 
Kyle Roger
```

Just a list of names, that's all

And this is the output:

[image: Notice the black space inbetween]

Comment: What do you mean "nothing comes out" ? Did it print wrong output? Did it not print anything at all? ran into an infinite loop? Only partial output? What exactly happens?

Comment: Show the file. Make debug output when you read and show that.

Comment: blank space, that's all. I run it in the terminal just fine, after that the command line is waiting for an input, that's it.

Comment: The program works fine for me after adding a missing `#include` and removing a broken comment. So if you're getting it to compile, it's probably fine. Maybe there's junk in your text file because it's unicode or something. Maybe the wrong file is being opened because of a path issue. But it's likely not a program with your program. (Make sure your `people.txt` file is roughly 58 bytes. If it's about double that, it's not a plain text file.)

Comment: The confusing thing is, I wrote another program earlier, with identical code, that ran perfect. I've no clue what's wrong with this one, the .txt file has 4 names in it, I doubt that's gonna clog it

Comment: How many lines your input file has? whats the n variable after that while loop?

Comment: Post the true complete code.  What is posted will not compile and we are left guessing what you truly have.

Comment: **Breakthrough:** apparently I was supposed to put `{` and `}` in the while loop. But I guess since none of you noticed it, i figured it wasn't mandatory.

 `while (..) {


}` always put brackets, even if there's just one command

Comment: @monolith937 Using `{...}` is a style issue - and a good idea, but does not explain the problem.  Suspect code was accessing a "people.txt" file with no data in it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this program and it ran fine. I created a people.txt with couple of names. Each line had firstname and lastname separated by a single space.

You may want to check how your input file is formatted. fscanf may be expecting name and lastname to be separated by just a single space.

Comment: "... expecting name and lastname to be separated by just a single space" is an invalid concern.  _single space_ is not a concern.  If the text file has multiple spaces or lines between names (first or last), it will not make a difference.

Comment: @chux. I agree with you. Two strings separated by any amount of whitespace or newlines should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the bad comment syntax, I don't see anything *obviously* wrong.  Your best bet would be to run this through a debugger line by line and check results as you go.  You're on a linux system building with gcc, so this should be dead simple:

```
$ gcc -g -o mk mk.c
$ gdb mk
(gdb) break main    
(gdb) r             
(gdb) n
```

`break main` sets a breakpoint at program entry, `r` starts the program, and `n` steps through the program line by line.  You can use the `p` command to print the value of different items as the program is executing:

```
(gdb) p n
(gdb) p array[n].name
(gdb) p array[n].lname
```

From now on, this should be the first thing you do when your program doesn't perform as you expect.

If you don't want to mess with a debugger (`gdb` isn't the best in the world, but it's really not that hard to use), then change your code so that you log your progress as you read your input file, something like the following:

```
int itemsRead;
...
while ( (itemsRead = fscanf( ... )) != EOF )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Expecting 2 items, read %d\n", itemsRead );
  switch( itemsRead )
  {
    case 2:
      fprintf( stderr, "array[%d].lname = %s\n", n, array[n].lname );
    case 1:
      fprintf( stderr, "array[%d].name  = %s\n", n, array[n].name );
    default:
      break;
  }
  if ( itemsRead < 2 )
    break;

  n++;
}
```

If nothing else, it should give you some idea of where the problem is.  If `itemsRead` comes back less than 2, then you may have a problem with how the file is formatted.

Answer (score -1):

```
*// Here I've tried even with >0 or  == 2, nothing worked) //*
```

is not a valid comment 
and:

```
for (i=o;i<n;i++)
```

is a typo. I guess what you meant is:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile though.

Comment: @BlueMoon It's what he posted.